# Obtener la média de una columna en un WHERE con MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Hola estoy realizando unos ejercicios de bases de datos, y tengo una duda en uno de ellos y es que no puedo obtener la média de una columna dentro de la cláusula `WHERE`, como se trata de un **`UPDATE`** tampoco puedo hacer una subconsulta a la propia tabla, aver si alguien me puede ayudar.

El enunciado dice así:

Rebaja en un **5%** el precio de todos los productos que cuesten menos de 1000 € y cuyo nivel de existencias sea mayor del doble de la media de las existencias de todos los productos.

[image: Tabla sobre la que se actua]

Lo que he hecho es esto pero da error de ejecución.

```
UPDATE ejercicio_31
set precio = precio - (precio * 0.05)
        where (precio < 1000 AND existencias > AVG(existencias)*2 );
```

Comment: Una muestra de los datos así como la estructura de la tabla nos ayudaría a poder apoyarte de forma mas efectiva, siempre y cuando no sean datos sensibles

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que da?

Comment: Que la función AVG() no está correctamente usada. Creo que en el WHERE no se puede utilizar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por un lado, `AVG` es una función de agregación, si no la usas con `GROUP BY` estarías aplicando el average sobre todas las filas en particular. Necesitas obtener ese dato mediante una sub-consulta. Ese es otro problema agregado, porque en MySQL no puedes usar directamente una consulta usando la misma tabla que intervendría en el `UPDATE`.

Esto podría solventarse de dos maneras al menos:

## 1. Usando una variable

Podrías calcular el average en una variable y luego usarla en el `WHERE`. Por ejemplo:

```
SET @media := (SELECT AVG(existencias)*2 FROM ejercicio_31);
UPDATE ejercicio_31
set precio = precio - (precio * 0.05)
where (precio < 1000 AND existencias > @media );
```

## 2. Usando una sub-consulta anidada

```
UPDATE ejercicio_31
    SET precio = precio - (precio * 0.05)
    WHERE ( 
             precio < 1000 AND 
             existencias > (SELECT * FROM (SELECT AVG(existencias)*2 FROM ejercicio_31) as aux)
           );
```

Hay otras formas de hacerlo con `JOIN` por ejemplo, pero en todos los casos es lo mismo.

Comment: Gracias, A. Cedano me ha funcionado correctamente, me he decantado por la subconsulta.

Comment: @JoseÁlvarez perfecto, me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

seria de la siguiente forma:

```
 UPDATE ejercicio_31
 set precio = precio - (precio * 0.05)
        where (precio < 1000)
        having (existencias > AVG(existencias));
```

Esa sería ya que avg, sum, etc se usa siempre dentro de having que de where...

Comment: ¿Cómo manejas en tu respuesta esta parte del enunciado?: **sea mayor del doble de la media**

Comment: Hola 7binary. Gracias por responder pero la cláusula having me da error